# The Spring Boot application can not find the webjar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I have an app in Spring Boot. I add dependence to gradle

```
    compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap:4.0.0'
```

then I add it to the HTML file

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

The HTML page code looks like this https://zapodaj.net/c19be4422007e.png.html
But the address of the CSS file does not work https://zapodaj.net/680da5d8a0371.png.html

Why is this happening? Apparently in Spring Boot just add dependence and should set everything up automatically.

Comment: to diagnose issues with webjars and the correct paths for the resources, one could open the final built `JAR`/`WAR` file of your application, go to `BOOT-INF/lib`, locate the actual `JAR` file fetched by webjars (e.g. for jQuery UI it would be `jquery-ui-X.X.X.jar`), open it and inspect the `META-INF/resources` path from there!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using maven. In your pom.xml add

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then in your html file this is how you should reference the webjar

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Make sure your dependency groupId is from "org.webjars"

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same issue as you. So after some research I have discover that WebJars have nothing to do with Spring in particular, So we have to define some mappings for those client dependencies with Spring MVC.

Lets suppose that you have this dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So try adding this configuration to your project and I think it will work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Then reference your code in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
```

or better in your thymeleaf:

```
<link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"  />
```

Comment: In my case, I cannot open link for bootstrap in the application on port 8702, but for another one on port 8701 with exact same link, it is totally fine. Quite weird.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else with Spring Boot 2 sees this - Using Spring Security, I faced this same issue and had to make several changes:

1. removed `@EnableWebMvc` in my configuration class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` so that the main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` can auto-configure
2. in the same config class as above, override the `addResourceHandlers()` method:

   ```
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/").resourceChain(false);
   }
   ```
3. In your Spring Security config class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, I had to do a few things:

   a. Let Spring auto-configure security by removing `@EnableWebSecurity`

   b. override `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method, as you're likely already doing, adding the ant matcher for allowing `/webjars/**`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll() 
     .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
   ```

   c. override the `configure(WebSecurity webSecurity)` method:

   ```
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
       webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**");
   }
   ```